# How to use fontTools to detect Type 1 and OpenType CFF fonts

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, ttx-fonttools

I know that it's possible to detect Type 1 and OpenType CFF (“PostScript flavored OpenType”) fonts by checking the first 4 bytes for 'OTTO' (0x4F54544F).

How would I do this in Python with the [fontTools](https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/) library? I.e., which font table would I need to check for this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version is stored in the font file header, not in a font data table. If you have a `ttLib.TTFont` object (i.e. you've opened a font file with fontTools), you can look at the `.sfntVersion` attribute of your `TTFont` object to get the version (which will usually be either `0x00010000`/Version 1 or `0x4F54544F`/OTTO, but there are other possible values, see below). But that kind of assumes you've already created a `TTFont` object by opening a font file, so this might be a kind of chicken-and-egg issue. If you're interested in knowing the version before you attempt to open the file/create a `TTFont`, you'll have to sniff the first four bytes (at least), outside of fontTools.

---

Note: I'm a little confused by your question. You mention Type 1, which is indeed a kind of PostScript font, but not (usually) the kind in OpenType/sfnt-housed fonts (that would be [**Type 2**](https://typekit.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/5176.cff.pdf), "Compact Font Format", or CFF). There *is* supposedly a way to store Type 1 in OpenType/sfnt-housed fonts; Apple mentions this in their [TrueType Reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6.html):

> The values 'true' (0x74727565) and 0x00010000 are recognized by OS X and iOS as referring to TrueType fonts. The value 'typ1' (0x74797031) is recognized as referring to the old style of PostScript font housed in a sfnt wrapper. The value 'OTTO' (0x4F54544F) indicates an OpenType font with PostScript outlines (that is, a 'CFF ' table instead of a 'glyf' table). Other values are not currently supported.

So if `typ1` is in fact what you're asking about, you could look for `0x74797031`/"typ1" in the first four bytes of the file. But actual `typ1` sfnt-housed fonts are exceedingly rare -- like almost non-existent. The overwhelming majority of actual Type 1 fonts will be in either .PFA/.PFB files (for non-Mac platforms), or in a "Printer Font" file (pre-OS X Mac), which would be paired with the old resource-fork "suitcase" file containing bitmaps. Type 1 font files will have `%!PS-AdobeFont-1` as the first bytes of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! For my purposes checking `.sfntVersion` is sufficient.